# Webpack 4 how to split code for tiny efficient chunks using SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, bundle

AngularJS 1.7.2 app, wrapped with Webpack 4, using one entry point and one output bundle js to be included in the distributed html file.

This is how I am using Webpack right now.

This is my entry.js file:

```
// angularjs app first initialization
var app = require('./app/app');

// app scripts
require('./app/index')(app);

// screens scripts
require('./screens/index')(app);

// shared scripts
require('./shared/index')(app);

// structure scripts
require('./structure/index')(app);
```

What in the `app` is this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngSanitize", "angular-loading-bar", "ngAnimate"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    template : require('../screens/auth/login/login.html')
  });
  cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
});

app.directive("app", function($rootScope, $location, Init, AutoRedirect, ObjectManipulation, Defaults) {
  return {
    template: require('./app.html'),
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      Init.start().then(function() {
        $scope.initialized = true;
        $rootScope.initSrc = true;
        $rootScope.$digest();
        AutoRedirect.fire();
      });

    }
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see I take the app instance of AngularJS and concatenate it through the whole app - I have 4 major routes:

1. app scripts
2. screens scripts (pages)
3. shared scripts (shared AngularJS components, like dropdown, button, autocomplete etc..)
4. structure scripts - which are the header, footer, sidebar menu etc...

Each route contains index.js file which imports the required modules, components and screens respectively.

This is an example of some module (login page controller) that is getting exported and important to the dependency graph:

```
// screens/auth/login/login.js    

module.exports = app => {

  require('./components/reset-password/reset-password')(app);
  require('./components/request-sms/request-sms')(app);

  app.config(($routeProvider, $locationProvider) => {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/auth/login", {
      template : require('./login.html')
    });
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

  app.controller("login", ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams) => {

    $scope.$on("request-sms", (e, info) => {
      $scope.phone = info.phone;
      $scope.waitingForSms = info.waitingForSms;
      $scope.requested = info.requested;
    }, true);

  });
}
```

Now as you can see, the above configuration of Webpack builds one bundle.js which has the whole app - all of its modules, all of its directives (components), all of its services and all its controller and dependencies.

This generates with big bundle.js file and the user downloads it at initial visit.

I wonder if Webpack does know if when user visits to some first initial view (not an html page, a view, since we are talking about an SPA) to load a bundle or something compiled code that is related only for this specific view? Ofcourse - and the basic build of the SPA.

I have read about code splitting at and seen some videos at Youtube but I don't get the concept and it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on using the [`SplitChunksPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimization-splitchunks) is a good introduction to how you can use `webpack` to create separate chunks from code. The [Dynamic Imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) section in the code splitting guide provides a quick introduction to splitting into asynchronous chunks using `import(name)` name expressions. This creates a manual chunk that is loaded asynchronously. The documentation on [`import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import) explains further usage.

These will help you instruct `webpack` to create chunks which will be separate files in the output. [`webpack` examples](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples) contains many sample configurations and their outputs so you can pick what's suitable for your needs.